# Unable to write new HTML content after closing the PrintWriter

Tags: java

---

Hi, I am unable to add the new content after closing the PrintWriter. Is there any other way to do this.

```
String myCurrentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
File htmlFile = new File(TestRunner.FilePath+"\\Footer.html");
final OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(htmlFile));
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);
writer.println("<HTML>");       
writer.println("<HEAD>");
writer.println("<title>Report Foot</title>");
writer.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\""+myCurrentDir+"/CSS/Report.CSS\">");
writer.println("</HEAD>");
writer.println("<body class = 'footer'>");
writer.println("<B>");
writer.println("Total : "+TotalTCs);
writer.println("<span class='passed'>Passed : "+0+"</span>");
writer.println("<span class='failed'>Failed : "+0+"</span>");
writer.println("<span class='warned'>Warned : "+0+"</span>");
writer.println("<span class='norun'>No Run : "+0+"</span>");
writer.println("</B>");
writer.println("<BR/>");
writer.println("<BR/>");
writer.close();//after this any content doesn't gets saved in html      
writer.println("@ABC DEF XYZ");
writer.println("</body>");
writer.println("</HTML>");
writer.close();
System.out.println("Footer Written");
```

Comment: Why do you need to close it in the middle?

Comment: Why do you think you can still write content after having closing it?

Answer (score 2):

Stream lifecycle is:

1. Createtion (`new Stream`)
2. Processing (`write`, `append`, so on)
3. Closing (`close`)

From `PrintWriter::close()` doc:

> Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated
>       with it.

[PrintWriter::close()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/PrintWriter.java#PrintWriter.close%28%29) sets `out = null` inside `PrintWriter`.
After closing you will get `IOException` at any call of `write`, `flush`, `print`, etc.
These methods call `ensureOpen()` before doing anything.

```
private void ensureOpen() throws IOException {
    if (out == null)
        throw new IOException("Stream closed");
    }
}
```